# jquery, how to get URL GET variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, get

i have a link:

```
<a href="?
processor=<?php echo $value['processor']; ?>&
auth_code=<?php echo $value['auth_code']; ?>
" id="buttonDetails">View Detail</a>
```

and a function:

```
function getUrlVars(parsedUrl) {
var vars = {};
parsedUrl.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,
        function(m, key, value) {
            vars[key] = value;
        });
return vars;
}
```

what i am doing is passing the link to this function;

```
var url = $('#buttonDetails').attr('href'); // "?processor=25&auth_code=12"
var first = getUrlVars(url);
alert (first );
```

this alert will give me `[object Object]`

any ideas what i am doing wrong?

edit:
another way would be to:

```
var first = getUrlVars()["processor"];
alert(processor);
```

but this doesn't work as well

edit:

the links are created in a php loop:

```
foreach($test as Value){
 // here is the link being created and the result is more links.
}
```

also i changed the `id` to `class` for the link.

and i'm doing:

```
$('.buttonDetails').each(function(){
var parsed = getUrlVars($(this).attr('href'));
console.log(parsed['processor']);

});
```

this will give me `undefined`

this `console.log(parsed);` will give me multiple objects with the data inside them. but when i try to get some specifics from inside the object i get `undefined`

why would this not work?

thanks again

Comment: `alert(getUrlVars(url)["processor"])`?

Comment: No error here. `first` is an object because you return one: `var vars = {}`. Alerting an object alerts `[object Object]`

Comment: my function needs a var to be passed to it

Comment: Related article: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html

Comment: Are you sure that this is putting the url to element?

Comment: Instead of `console.log(parsed)` use `console.log(Object.keys(parsed))` which will return keys of the object (like "processor" and "auth_code"). That should help you to indentify the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this example:

```
var url = $('#buttonDetails').attr('href'); // "?processor=25&auth_code=12"
var first = getUrlVars(url);
alert (first );
```

The reason the alert gives you `[object Object]` is because that's what `first` is:

```
Object
    auth_code: "12"
    processor: "25"
```

Your second example doesn't work because you are not passing a value to the `getUrlVars` function. Try this:

```
var url = $('#buttonDetails').attr('href'), // "?processor=25&auth_code=12"
    parsed = getUrlVars(url);

alert(parsed['processor']);
```

Comment: @Patrioticcow, are you sure you didn't mistype the 'processor' in either the url or the `parsed['processor']` part? Because this works perfectly for me. [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PYQe2/)

Comment: It's working fine here. You've got something wrong somewhere.. can you provide a pastebin link with the full code? I'll try to help.

Comment: Also, I'd just like to specify that the reason he gets `[object Object]` is because the object's toString function (Object.prototype.toString because it wasn't overridden) always returns `"[object Object]"`. I've found this useful to know in some situations.

Comment: wired, it doesn't work on my pc... but i see it working in the jsfiddle

Comment: put your code on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com and link it, also feel free to try my solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't have a built in function. I use this: http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

```
var first = getUrlVars(url)["processor"];
alert(first); // not alert(processor)
```

or

```
var first = getUrlVars(url);
alert (first.processor); // or alert(first["processor"]
```